# Spring boot TEST with inmemory database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My problem is that i'm not able to create test which use in memory database. All the times got errors, for example:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages

How could i do the test with H2 inmemory database?

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "names")
public class Names{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "name_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository("namesRepository")
public interface NamesRepository extends JpaRepository<Names, Long> {

    Names findByName(String name);
    List<Names> findAll();
}
```

Database config class:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.dbProfileService")
    @Primary
    public DataSource createProfileServiceDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate_ProfileService(DataSource profileServiceDS) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(profileServiceDS);
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
      application:
        name: app
      dbProfileService: 
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres"
        password: "postgres"
        username: "postgres"
        testOnBorrow: false
        testWhileIdle: false
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 60000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 30000
        validationQuery: SELECT 1
        max-active: 15
        max-idle: 10
        max-wait: 8000
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @DataJpaTest
  @SpringBootConfiguration
    public class NamesTest {

        @Autowired
        private NamesRepository names;

        @Test
        public void firsTest(){

        }
    }
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile(group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.2')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '4.0.2.GA'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Please add **@AutoConfigurationPackage** to the **@SpringBootConfiguration** class, it needed because there is no **@SpringBootApplication** class in the sample:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class NamesTest {

    @Autowired
    private NamesRepository names;

    @Test
    public void firsTest(){

    }
}
```

Comment: After your changes: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ->>Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Comment: Remove the dependency
spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: disable JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
})